# Maven not resolve apt-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven

I added an apt-maven-plugin to my pom.xml but maven shows me a statement "Element additional source root is not allowed here".

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/annotations</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        <additionalSourceRoots>
                            <additionalSourceRoot>target/generated-sources/annotations</additionalSourceRoot>
                        </additionalSourceRoots>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: what is the IDE you are using?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2016.4

Comment: can you try File->Invalidate Caches->Invalidate and Restart. coz this solved my problem.

Comment: It doesn't work still.

Comment: what is the server you are using?

Comment: try this: write the whole <configuration> tag data outside of <executions>